# Why does Shiny fire twice?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a Shiny app where a chart is updated based on user selection when a previous selection exists. I have noticed that, for some reason that I cannot figure out, Shiny fires twice: first with the previous selection, and second, with the new selection. For example, in the example below, when the users starts off by selecting "Data1" and goes to "Tab1" where the chart using "var1" is correctly displayed. When the user now goes back to "Tab1" via the "Back" button and selects "Data2", the previous chart using "var1" is displayed for an instant and then replaced by the correct chart using "var2". The chart for the first selection is only visible very briefly which is why I inserted a delay in the example below to make the problem more obvious. How can I prevent the previous chart to appear?

Note: The code below is minimal. It doesn't include restrictions, e.g. preventing the user from only selecting "Data1" or "Data2" since this is not pertinent to the problem. I have also found the same problem when I use checkboxes instead of action buttons for the input and observe the checkbox input directly when rending the charts.

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(shinyjs)

df <- data.frame(cbind(seq(2001, 2020, by=1),
                       sample(1:15, size=20, replace=T),
                       sample(1:15, size=20, replace=T))) 
colnames(df) <- c("year", "var1", "var2")
df

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Title", 
  id = "navbar", 
  useShinyjs(),
  
  tabsetPanel(id="tabs", 
              tabPanel(title = "Selection", value = "tab1",
                       fluidRow(
                         column(4,
                       actionButton("action1", "Data1"),
                         ),
                       column(4,
                       actionButton("action2", "Data2")
                       )
                       ),
                       fluidRow(
                       actionButton("action3", "Next")
                       )
              )
              
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  chart <- reactiveValues(selection = "")
  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    chart$selection <- "data1"
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$action2, {
    chart$selection <- "data2"
  })
 
    observeEvent(input$action3, {  
    if (chart$selection == "data1") {
      delay(1000, output$chart <- renderUI({
        highchart() %>%
          hc_add_series(df, type = "line",
                        hcaes(
                          x = year,
                          y = var1
                        ))
      }))
      
    } else if (chart$selection == "data2") {
      delay(1000, output$chart <- renderUI({
      highchart() %>%
        hc_add_series(df, type = "line",
                      hcaes(
                        x = year,
                        y = var2
                      ), color="black")
    }))
    }
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$action3, {
    insertTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "tab1", select=T,
              tabPanel(title = "Chart", value = "tab2",
                       fluidRow(
                         uiOutput("chart")
                       ),
                       fluidRow(
                         actionButton("action4", "Back")
                       )
              ) 
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$action4, {
  updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs", selected="tab1")
    removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target ="tab2")
  })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that there is an indeterminacy in your app as you have two `observeEvent`s which both listen to `input$action3`.

One option to fix your issue and to solve this indeterminacy would be to update your chart first when the user presses the `Next` button and only then to switch the tab. To this end I replaced the first `observeEvent` by an `eventReactive` to create the chart which could then be used to trigger the action to insert I the UI and to display the updated chart:

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Title",
  id = "navbar",
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabs",
    tabPanel(
      title = "Selection", value = "tab1",
      fluidRow(
        column(
          4,
          actionButton("action1", "Data1"),
        ),
        column(
          4,
          actionButton("action2", "Data2")
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        actionButton("action3", "Next")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  chart <- reactiveValues(selection = "")
  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    chart$selection <- "data1"
  })

  observeEvent(input$action2, {
    chart$selection <- "data2"
  })

  hchart <- eventReactive(input$action3, {
    if (chart$selection == "data1") {
      highchart() %>%
        hc_add_series(df,
          type = "line",
          hcaes(
            x = year,
            y = var1
          )
        )
    } else if (chart$selection == "data2") {
      highchart() %>%
        hc_add_series(df,
          type = "line",
          hcaes(
            x = year,
            y = var2
          ), color = "black"
        )
    }
  })

  output$chart <- renderUI({ hchart() })

  observeEvent(hchart(), {
    insertTab(
      inputId = "tabs", target = "tab1", select = T,
      tabPanel(
        title = "Chart", value = "tab2",
        fluidRow(
          uiOutput("chart")
        ),
        fluidRow(
          actionButton("action4", "Back")
        )
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$action4, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs", selected = "tab1")
    removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "tab2")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly for the example above. In my actual app, I have three columns on the "tab2" page which each have charts and other elements. The number of columns (1, 2, or 3) is determined by how many action buttons the user selects. I adapted the solution above by creating several reactive events (e.g. "hchart1", "hchart2" etc.) for all the elements needed in each column. But e.g. in case of three columns, shiny fires three times which makes sense given the explanation above. How can I adapt the code to accommodate several reactive events without incurring indeterminacy again?